# jQuery cloning issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone a row into content by creating unique ID yet I am facing some issues.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="email-container" class="email-container">
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Email">
            <span class="plus-button">+</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.plus-button').click(function(){
    $('.email-container').clone().insertAfter(".email-container").end();
    $('.email-container').find('.plus-button').text('-').not(':last-child');
});
```

​
Please find my fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/GCRVS/3/

I am trying to clone `#email-container` and add it inside `.content` with clearing the textbox values and also need to change the `.plus-button` value to "-" except the last row.

Comment: Having live examples is great, but please make your questions complete without having to go off to an external site (which has the potential to go away independently of SO).

Comment: You also have three separate questions here. Please deal with them one at a time and not bundle them all up into one question. Also please **search** there is no shortage of questions about validating email addresses in text boxes in JavaScript.

Comment: I have removed my other questions..sorry abt that..

Comment: You should [read about placeholder attributes](http://www.pardot.com/help/faqs/best-practices/placeholders-and-labels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="email-container" class="email-container">
        <input class="1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email">
        <input class="1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="plus-button">+</span>
    </div> 
</div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.plus-button').click(AddNewRow);
});

function AddNewRow(event)
{
   var clone = $('.email-container').last().clone().appendTo('.content');
   clone.children('.1').val(''); //delete all values of your clone
   clone.children('.plus-button').bind('click', AddNewRow);

   var btn = $(this).parent().find('.plus-button');  //The cloned button
   btn.text('-');
   btn.removeClass('plus-button');
   btn.addClass('minus-button');
   btn.unbind('click');  //unbind the "old" click event
   btn.click(RemoveRow);
}


function RemoveRow(event)
{
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

This should do the trick.
TIPP: When you are creating new elements in your DOM you should bind the item manually or use "on"

EDIT: Removed .live() because of its deprecation

Comment: Please note that `live` has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the amazing code..I felt the live code made my code work smoother than other events:)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
And you don't need the id #email-container.

```
$(document).on('click', '.plus-button', function(){
    var content = $(this).text();
    if(content == '+'){
        $(this).parent().clone(true, true).insertAfter($(this).parent());
        $('.email-container').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).is(':last-child')){
                $(this).find('.plus-button').html('-');
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().remove();

    }
});
```

EDIT: I made a major edit inserting the if/else to also address the remove issue...

EDIT2: It has to say insertAfter($(this).parent()

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically generated elements, the click event should be delegated, you can use the `on` method, note that I have removed the ID attribute from your markup as IDs should be unique and having same ID attributes in the document makes it invalid. Try the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.plus-button', function(){
    $('.email-container:last').clone().insertAfter(".email-container:last")
    $('.email-container:not(:last)').find('.plus-button').attr('class', 'remove').text('-');
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove ', function(){
    $(this).closest('.email-container').remove();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCRVS/21/)